# What should be in and what should be out of a jQuery.ready()?

Tags: jquery, optimization, domready

What should be in and what should be out of a jQuery.ready() ?

On a performance perspective, I've read somewhere that putting all the codes wrapped inside a `jQuery.ready()` isn't an efficient way to go.

Then my question is : what should be in and what can be oustide without problems (I guess delegates could be kept outside but it's a fast guessing) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ultimate performance put your js before the closing body tag. That way you can eliminate jquery ready altogether. The UI loads fast as it is [not blocked](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) by scripts being downloaded and when the js is parsed and invoked you can be sure the elements in the dom above are ready to be manipulated.

Comment: Good tips. But about the jQuery codes, what kind of codes (events, ajax, ...) could actually lives outside a DOM ready with no problem?

Comment: @Cybrix All of them if you include scripts at the bottom!

Comment: Sorry you answered it right the first time. I was just reading your answer a little bit too fast. :P

Comment: Does it matter if the script is inline or called externaly?

Comment: @Cybix - well by inline do you mean an js event attribute on an element e.g onclick. If this is he case no - but I would strongly advise against any inline events. Abstract it away into separate js files. Try not to mix markup and js

Comment: By inline, I mean the javascript inserted between `<script>` tags versus external js files using `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.ready() is called after the page is done loading.  See first sentence in [jQuery.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). If you want events to fire before the page is done loading jQuery.ready() would not be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep function delcarations such as

```
fnc = function() { ... };
```

or any other declaration. Because if you shove it all in, that code will start executing only when the whole DOM has loaded. Otherwise, it starts executing as soon as it downloaded. The jQuery wrapper should only be present when your javascript requires the DOM to be downloaded.

```
var blah = function() {
   //...
};

$(function() { //same as jQuery(document).ready or $(document).ready
    blah();
});
```

Comment: But then you bloat the window object with all your function decs. Better declare the functions within a single app namespace.